# Java 9 IntelliJ Groovy openCSV not finding dependency java/sql/ResultSet

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, java-9, opencsv

I am using Groovy 2.4 with openCSV  in Java 9. When I try to run the program with in IDE its not finding the ResutlSet class file.  But it works in Gradle task.

Any help to resolve this error message?

**Gradle task**

```
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv
    compile group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '4.0'

task runApp(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'mongo.UserReport'
}
```

**Stack trace**

```
Error:Groovyc: While compiling Tools_main: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class com.opencsv.CSVWriter due to missing dependency java/sql/ResultSet
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1101)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1079)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovyCompilerWrapper.compile(GroovyCompilerWrapper.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.DependentGroovycRunner.runGroovyc(DependentGroovycRunner.java:115)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.intMain2(GroovycRunner.java:136)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.runGroovycInThisProcess(InProcessGroovyc.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.lambda$runGroovyc$0(InProcessGroovyc.java:88)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class com.opencsv.CSVWriter due to missing dependency java/sql/ResultSet
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:397)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:1009)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:1004)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getSuperClass(ClassNode.java:998)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.isDerivedFrom(ClassNode.java:941)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.castToNonPrimitiveIfNecessary(InvocationWriter.java:863)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OperandStack.doConvertAndCast(OperandStack.java:345)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OperandStack.doGroovyCast(OperandStack.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.BinaryExpressionHelper.evaluateEqual(BinaryExpressionHelper.java:344)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitDeclarationExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:664)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.DeclarationExpression.visit(DeclarationExpression.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(StatementWriter.java:613)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:366)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitExpressionStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:651)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(StatementWriter.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitStdMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:461)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitConstructorOrMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:538)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1081)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitClass(AsmClassGenerator.java:260)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$17.call(CompilationUnit.java:825)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1065)
```

Comment: Silly question but did you import the project as a Gradle project?

Comment: yes, my project run if comment out `CSVWriter ` part of the code

Comment: Sorry, what I mean was...did you import as a Gradle project recently?  If not, close it.  Import, and select the directory and chose Gradle.  Say yes on overwrite existing IntelliJ files.  That should force it to import the dependency for CSVWriter.

Comment: @ToddWCrone tried  your recommendation, its giving me the same error 'ava.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class com.opencsv.CSVWriter due to missing dependency java/sql/ResultSet'

Comment: Ok, do you have a database driver on the classpath?

Comment: NCDFE loading java.sql.ResultSet suggests there may be a custom class loader in the picture that assumes that all platform classes are loaded by the bootstrap class loader. Code that makes this assumption needs to be fixed to delegate to the platform class loader. More on this in the JDK 9 release notes. I can't tell from question whether the issue is with Groovy or openCSV- best to check the site for both to see which versions are needed to run on JDK 9 and JDK 10.

Comment: @AlanBateman today I updated the IntelliJ to new release. it started working. Thanks for the tips. Can you update the answer I will accept it.